# Clear browser cache when redirected from third party login

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

So the user is logged out on a page that is usually cached for 60 seconds, because of heavy traffic. The user wants to do an action on that page witch requires the user to sign in.
When the user clicks on the action they are redirected to another domain to sign inn. The site is using a third party login and they are sent directly to that page. After the login is successful they are redirected pack to the original page. Since the original page is cached they receive a 302 from the server when they return from the third party site.

The bad thing that happens is that because of the cache if the user tries to do the action again they are redirected back to login and then back again until the cache expires. My first attempt to fix this is to ad a url parameter when you are redirected from sign in back to the original page. This seems like a hack. Is there a better way to handle this problem?

This is in a Java Spring app if that is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get around the complete problem is not to cache and use the E-Tag header instead.